# How to copy array string values into Range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Pasted below is my script. I am copying a particular range of values from a sheet called "TalukaName" and copying it into "UserInterface!I2:I" cells. When I try to copy the values from the array into a Range, i get the error

> Cannot convert Array to Object

at the line where I `setValues` of the Range. All my values that need to be copied into the Range are String values. Hence I added double quotes while creating array. Can anybody please help as to what is going wrong?

```
function test(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('UserInterface'), true);
  var count = ss.getRange("H2").setFormula('=countif(TalukaName!B:B,UserInterface!C2)').getValue();
  var DistrictName = ss.getRange('C2').getValue(); 
  var matchindex = ss.getRange('H3').setFormula('=match(C2,TalukaName!B:B,0)').getValue(); 
  var indexvalue = ss.getRange('H4').setFormula('=index(TalukaName!B:B,H3)').getValue();

  var array = [];
  var ssTaluka = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TalukaName'), true);  
  var range = ssTaluka.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    array[i]=  '"' + data[i+matchindex-1][0] + '"'; 
  }

  ss.getRange('I2:I').setValues(array);
}
```

Comment: `setValues` expects an Array whose elements are also Arrays. The elements of the inner arrays are to be the values in that row.

Comment: Thank you. I converted it into another array for setvalues and it got resolved